# Removing sock puppet accounts

Tags: discussion

Lately we've been experiencing a sock puppet issue. This person has multiple accounts, they create poor answers and poor questions. It appears they're now [upvoting poor questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56689/3d-object-manipulation-framework) (or it's another sock puppet in the making, or they're trying to confuse their trail by upvoting accounts that aren't theirs, 6 votes in 6 minutes on a question like that is a dead give away). When I make comments they just use his accounts to flag my comments enough to get automatically removed. A moderator can confirm the deleted comments on the question I linked.

Do we not have a better way to track down people abusing the site like this?

Obviously it's not going to be a long term problem for this one person, since they'll get bored of the trolling. But it would be nice to remove users like this when they are potentially disrupting legitimate users questions/answers.

Comment: I think I've either deleted or destroyed most of the sock puppet accounts already.

Comment: Based on the activity today, I'd have to disagree :) My comments were being flagged and auto removed in less than a minute. I assume one account doesn't have that kind of control.

Comment: Looks like there's something very fishy going on with that account. See these [reputation events](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/31353/regeta?tab=reputation)...

Comment: The same account mentioned above by @AndrewRussell has been causing some problems today as well, on the GD.SE Community Moderator Nominations page. They've flagged several of Byte56's posts to the point of auto-deletion.

Comment: Perhaps the sock puppet user can post a question on meta about the issues they have with the site. Listing evidence of where they think new users were wronged, and how they propose the issue be solved. It would be far more effective than the activity that's been taking place.

Comment: I'm seeing more of this (?) at the moment... the OP clearly stated that they didn't want to hear about chunking (see edit), yet the upvotes keep coming to a useless answer on an otherwise new account. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103067/how-do-game-engines-mitigate-cpu-cost-for-many-trigger-zones-entities/103085#103085