# How does meta reputation work, especially when I get reputation removed in main?

Tags: support, reputation

So today I get a boost to reputation and then it was taken back. Looks like it has something to do with sock puppet accounts mentioned in another question: [Removing sock puppet accounts](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1150/30949)

I visited meta before and noticed that I have the same reputation as in main. Now after the reputation on main got removed, I still have the higher number here in meta.

How does reputation on meta work? Is it the maximum reputation ever reached? Asking out of sheer curiosity.

---

OT, feel free to ignore: Also I noticed that stackoverflow meta has separate login from main. So I guess the reputation there works differently?

Comment: From my understanding they try to stay in sync but it takes a while for changes on main to migrate to meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant Blog Post : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Like Tetrad said in his comment, it takes about a day, there are processes that run that sync data across. The point is that the higher your involvement in the main site, the greater your stake and your meta reputation should reflect that.

Meta StackOverflow is a bit different though

> For now we are leaving meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still a standalone community with a standalone reputation system. We think Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this, and it just so happens that Stack Overflow is also the name of the company, too. Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals. So, in a nutshell:

Of course, this is in the process of changing as well : [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: The blog made it quite clear. Thanks